# firebase select count for 1 day

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So Lets say i have a few of data on 1 day and another set of data on another day. These data will store in the same table. Is there a way for me to select count for each day: like lets say Day 1 has 20 counts and Day 2 has 13 counts?[image]

Comment: query by time field that will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to add another child to your object. Call it `date` and save the date as `YYYYMMDD`. This gives you a date stamp on each object.

Then you can do a query like;

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('/Button_Log')
  .orderByChild('date')
  .equalTo('20170818')
   .once('value')
   .then(snapshot => {
     console.log(snapshot.numChildren());   // Number of records
   });
```

Otherwise if you don't want a new child, you could try something like;

```
firebase.database()
  .ref('/Button_Log')
  .orderByChild('time')
  .startAt('2017-08-10')
  .endAt('2017-08-10 23:59:59')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.numChildren());  // Number of records
  });
```

**EDIT**

Thomas has suggested that you use UNIX timestamp as it's more flexible.

When savings the data set the created timestamp as `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` this will save the timestamp.

Then you can do a query like;

```
var startOfDay = new Date();
startOfDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);

var endOfDay = new Date();
endOfDay.setHours(23,59,59,999);

firebase.database()
  .ref('/Button_Log')
  .orderByChild('timestamp')
  .startAt(startOfDay)
  .endAt(endOfDay)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.numChildren()); // Number of records
  });
```

Comment: It'd use the unix timestamp as int instead of the date string, it allows you to specify a time too if needed later => more scalability.

Comment: What if you want to query over a span. So day 1 has 20; day 2 has 8; day 3 has 10; day 4 has 0; day 5 has 0; day 6 has 1; and day 7 has 11. So if I have a page that is currently displaying for 1 day, but then user clicks weekly, i would need to show the entire count for the 7 days?